# Resource bundle not found for MessageSource

Tags: java, spring

I want to retrieve value from properties file, but ApplicationContext cannot find the that file, I don't know why. see my code and screen shot:

spring_part22.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">           

    <bean id="point1" class="org.dxc.java.technology.part22.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"></property>
        <property name="y" value="0"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.dxc.java.technology.part22" />
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessage_en_US.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Location of mymessage.properties:

[image]

Drive.java

```
public class Drive {

    static ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ConfigurationFiles/spring_part22.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
    }

    static void test1() {

        System.out.println(context.getMessage("greeting", null, "Default Greeting", null));

    }
}
```

When I run main function, I get following output :

```
Apr 15, 2017 11:42:39 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@497470ed: startup date [Sat Apr 15 11:42:39 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 15, 2017 11:42:39 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ConfigurationFiles/spring_part22.xml]
Apr 15, 2017 11:42:40 AM org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource getResourceBundle
WARNING: ResourceBundle [mymessage_en_US.properties] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name mymessage_en_US.properties, locale en_US
Default Greeting
```

I don't know why springframework cannot find that property file, can anyone help me or tell me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<value>mymessage_en_US.properties</value>
```

use this

```
<value>mymessage</value>
```